# Relationship between locks and atomic operations in thread programming

Tags: multithreading, locking, atomic

Are all locks implemented using atomic operations? In some book, it says "one lock needs several atomic operations". I thought atomic operations and locks are different things. But it seems I was wrong. What's the relationship between locks and atomic operations?

Comment: Automobiles and wheels are different things. How is it possible that one automobile can need several wheels?

Comment: The confusion is understandable though, since lock-free programming is the only place where you come in contact with atomics, so it is easy to come to the conclusion that atomics = lock-free and since lock-free is the opposite of locking, atomics are the opposite of locking. You have to consider from the tone of the question that OP is new to it and does not know very well what exactly atomics and locks are.

Answer (score 4):

**Locks and atomics** 
Locks are a protection mechanism to perform complex, thread-unsafe operations on some data that is protected by the lock. [Atomic operations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) are operations that can never be observed only part-way through, and are not interrupted if multiple threads are simultaneously accessing the same variables (note that in C++, variables on which atomic operations are performed are called atomic too). Locks are an abstract concept implemented using atomic operations.

**How to use mutexes / locks** 
A [mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) is the standard way to perform locking: A mutex always guards some variables that are associated with it. It is either locked or unlocked, and only one thread at a time can lock it. While the mutex is locked, the thread can perform thread-unsafe operations on its guarded variables, and it is guaranteed that no other thread can interfere or observe partial changes made by the thread that holds the lock. After the thread is done modifying the variables, it can unlock the mutex, so that other threads can now access the guarded variables (by locking the mutex themselves).

Note that whenever a thread wants to access any of the protected variables in any way, it needs to lock the associated mutex. Otherwise, it is no longer guaranteed that threads won't interfere with each other's work.

**How are locks implemented?** 
As far as I know, locks/mutexes are always implemented using atomic operations. One such operation is the *[atomic exchange](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/exchange)*: It allows you to read a value from a variable, and write a new value to it, atomically, so no other thread can interfere in this process or observe it half-way done. A mutex would be implemented using an atomic bool (true = LOCKED, false = UNLOCKED), and locking it is performed by performing the following:

```cpp
while(mutex.locked.exchange(LOCKED) == LOCKED);
```

This always sets the mutex to LOCKED, and reads the previous value, and if it was UNLOCKED, finishes. In this scenario, we are the only thread that set the mutex from UNLOCKED to LOCKED.

Unlocking is very simple: `mutex.locked = UNLOCKED;` This simply sets the mutex to UNLOCKED, and it can then be locked again by other threads.

**Note** 
For simplicity, I did leave out [memory ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order), an aspect of atomics which deals with the order in which changes made by one thread become visible to other threads (as with some memory orders, changes may be observed in a different order than in which they were made, and multiple threads may even see changes in inconsistent orders). Memory ordering is very complex to get into.

**Conclusion** 
As a general rule of thumb, unless you really know what you're doing, you should always use mutexes and locks, and not atomics. Although mutexes are slower, they are complex enough to get into already, and are much easier to use correctly. They automatically deal with visibility of changes made, so your program becomes easier to understand and write.

Comment: Re, "While the mutex is locked...it is guaranteed that no other thread can interfere or observe partial changes..." That is not guaranteed by any locking library that I know of. Most make two guarantees: (1) no more than one thread will ever be allowed to own the mutex at the same time, and (2) whatever thread A does in memory before releasing a lock will be visible to thread B after thread B subsequently locks the same lock. Any other guarantees (e.g., that thread B won't look at data while thread A changes it) are the responsibility of the programmer who writes the code that uses the locks.

Comment: I was simplifying things, since OP obviously is new to multithreaded programming. But thanks for the hint, I will add a clarification to my answer.